# How would you accommodate this requirement in EF4.0

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I have a new circumstances (for me anyway) and wonder what is the best way to do this in EF4.0, (database first). This is a madeup example, but it mimics the logic of what I need to do:

Say you have just two tables PEOPLE and TEAMS, each team has a team leader and a backup team leader. The people table has a single record for each person, with a unique ID, the team record has a unique ID, but also a TeamLeaderID and a BackupTeamLeaderId, which map to the people table.

How do you handle this in EF? If I only had a teamleaderid, I could access it by Team.People.Name, but since I know have two links from teams->people this design will not work.

I can think of lots of kludgy scenarios for this, but what is the proper way to set this up in EF (or alternatively resdesign the underlying tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are starting with an EF question. Do you have your database schema worked out? If so, present that. If not, then I'd start there.

Your Team table will need a Leader foreign key to the People table. If any person can only be in one team, then you could add a TeamID column to your People table. Each person with TempID set to a particular Team would be a player on that team.

Comment: Assume the people table has just two fields: id and name, the team table has 4 fields, ID, TeamName and TeamLeaderID, BackupTeamLeaderID. I have a foreign key for teamleaderid to the people table and backupteamleaderid to the people table....so how do I get the backupteamleaders name? If I do team.people.name, how will that work? (Every person could be on more than one team, and a team leader on on team maybe a backupteamleader on another, and vice versa.)

Comment: If I follow what you're saying, it would be something like `team.BackupTeamLeaderID.Name` (assuming `BackupTeamLeaderID` is a foreign key). But I'm still fuzzy on some of the details.

Comment: OK, you didn't quite nail it, but you lead me to the answer, so I'll give you credit. I needed to manually add a second naviation property called 'backupteamleader' that uses the backupteamleader foreignkey; upto this point I've only relied on the default navigation properties that are added when you add the table to the model (assuming the foreign keys are setup properly).